# response from requests.session object differs from browser's response

Tags: python, debugging, web-scraping, python-requests

This is a python script using requests.

I was tasked with solving a bug. But I have come to found it is currently outside of my understanding.

The project itself is just a domain name availability checker against a registrar service. It does not query an API but the actual webpage and scrapes it for the result.

Now, the tasks arises because the project manager gets the correct results on his browser. i.e He queries for 'sakura.ne.jp' and he gets 'Not available'. But the script returns 'Available' as result.

I thought this would be an easy fix but turns out I don't get consistent results from the site when I query it myself. Sometimes I get 'Available', sometimes it gives me 'Not Available'. I have tried in both firefox and Chrome.

Having said this, the script ONLY gets 'Available'. Every try.

I was a little confused by the non-consisten behaviour of the web-browser requests, but knowing what the correct result is I can move forward.

The thing is I don't know where to start. I am now going to compare my own requests (Available/Not Available and see the difference to see if there is something of use)

I tried using the project manager's request headers in the script instead of the defaults but it didn't give me the same response.

I have read online and there seems to be some errors whenever .ne.jp DL is involved.

Does anybody have any suggestion? Or know what is going on? What would you do? Is there anything I haven't checked, tried or done that you would have?